# one GET request but caught by multiple .get functions in express, node.js

Tags: node.js, express, nonblocking, url-parameters

The client just sent one request but multiple .get functions are catching the request.

Here's my code.

```
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('home');
    res.send('home');
});

app.get('/:var1', (req, res) => {
    console.log('var1');
    res.send('var1');
});

app.get('/:var1/:var2', (req, res) => {
    console.log('var2');
    res.send('var2');
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('listening in 4000')
});
```

What I expected was

```
when /:
 console: home
 browser: home
when /foo:
 console: var1
 browser: var1
when /foo/bar:
 condole: var2
 browser: var2
```

However, the actual result was

```
when /:
 console: home and var1
 browser: home
when /foo:
 console: var1 and var1
 browser: var1
when /foo/bar:
 condole: var2 and var1
 browser: var2
```

If the result was because of NonBlocking-IO, why are there var1 two times?
And why did the browser get only one response?
How can I change the result using express routing?

Comment: This is due to Express routing behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The above behaviour is Express routing.

In design standpoint you don't need 3 different routes for simple params change

you can go with

```
const app = express()

app.get('/?var1=12&var2=34', (req, res) => {
    console.log('home');
     var params = req.query.var1.
    res.send('home');
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('listening in 4000')
});
```

You can handle all in single route

Comment: Sorry but what I wanted was routing.. I'll add it to question